# The code below runs but will never display a button for me. I just want a simple button that says quit

Tags: python

I am trying to learn GUI on PyQt5 (which I have downloaded) and I want to create a button. After looking at a decent amount of articles the problem still persists.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(700,250,700,500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Hang-Man")
        self.show()

    def home(self):
        btn1 = QPushButton('Quit', self)
        btn1.move(20,200)
        self.show()
```

Comment: Where do you call this class? Does your QT GUI appear as a blank canvas? Also note that PyQt5 has a drag and drop interface to make the GUI just to let you know :).

Comment: @Laurent LAPORTE sorry I meant to also put in import sys, also thank you for fixing my presentation of the question this was my first time using the cite, also yes it does show up as a blank canvas

Comment: @AustinFoster, `sys` is not used in your sample.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Thank you again for fixing that mistake!

Comment: Looks like you are using `super` wrong. Use `super().__init__()`. Also call the `home` method in your constructor. The easiest way to debug is to look at similar code [that works](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/menustoolbars/).

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE so i just tried copying and pasting what you said and there was still a blank canvas as before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know what is your `home` method, but the right way to do that is to define your UI widgets in the `initUI` method, like that:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(700, 250, 700, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Hang-Man")

        btn1 = QPushButton('Quit', self)
        btn1.move(20, 200)
        btn1.clicked.connect(self.close)

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here, the "clicked" handler is connected to the `close` method, to close the application.

Comment: It was calling upon itself that i was missing. I was looking at a lot of PyQt4 tutorials when doing this practice. Thank you so much i appreciate this!

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept this answer and upvote.

Comment: also does having my def of home make a difference since i called it home instead of initUI, or is it more of a general format?

Comment: Well, I think `initUI` is a naming convention, so you can choose another name if you want. But, you need to call it from `__init__`. Don't forget to call `show` at the end of your initialisation.